# mapping categorical variable in ggmap in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

am having this data

```
Zip    incidentType        city state latitude longitude
1 00660           Flood Hormigueros    PR 18.13911 -67.12085
2 00660 Severe Storm(s) Hormigueros    PR 18.13911 -67.12085
3 00660 Severe Storm(s) Hormigueros    PR 18.13911 -67.12085
4 00660           Flood Hormigueros    PR 18.13911 -67.12085
5 00660           Flood Hormigueros    PR 18.13911 -67.12085
6 01255           Flood Sandisfield    MA 42.08897 -73.12444
```

and i want to great a heat map to plot incident variable which is a factor with various levels with the following code

```
library(ggmap)

map <- get_map(location = "United States",zoom = 4,maptype = "terrain",
               color = "color",source = "google")

ggmap(map,extent = "device") + geom_point(aes(x=latitude,y=longitude,
                         alpha=0.7,fill=incidentType,
                        col=incidentType),fun=sum,
                        data = dat1,na.rm = TRUE)
```

But the points are not plotted on the map.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple issues.

1. `zoom = 4` is too small. Please use `zoom = 3`.
2. `longitude` should be mapped to `x`. `latitude` should be mapped to `y`.
3. It is better to specify the `ggplot` call in the `base_layer` argument.
4. Not sure what does `fun = sum` mean here.
5. Not sure why `alpha = 0.7` is the in `aes` argument.

Here is the fixed code.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Zip    incidentType        city state latitude longitude
1 00660           Flood Hormigueros    PR 18.13911 -67.12085
2 00660 'Severe Storm(s)' Hormigueros    PR 18.13911 -67.12085
3 00660 'Severe Storm(s)' Hormigueros    PR 18.13911 -67.12085
4 00660           Flood Hormigueros    PR 18.13911 -67.12085
5 00660           Flood Hormigueros    PR 18.13911 -67.12085
6 01255           Flood Sandisfield    MA 42.08897 -73.12444",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(ggmap)

map <- get_map(location = "United States",zoom = 3,maptype = "terrain",
               color = "color",source = "google")

ggmap(map, 
      base_layer = ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude))) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = incidentType, col = incidentType), alpha = 0.7, size = 2)
```

Here is the plot.

[image]

Comment: have do that but now am getting an error HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'

Comment: What is the error? And did you get the error from the example I posted, or your real-world dataset?

Comment: It seems like your internet has some problems.

Comment: real-world dataset "HTTP status was '403 Forbidden' "

Comment: I saw you posted another question and I marked that as a duplicate. You should be able to learn something from that duplicated post.

Comment: I was able generate the map, but i would like to ask another question concerning the same, but i need to post the plot for you to see to be able to effectively help me. How do you post the plot like the one you posted above?

Comment: You need to have enough reputation to post a plot. What you can do is post your question with a web link to your plot, and then I can help you by editing your post and let the plot shown.

Comment: If my post solved your question, please accept it as the answer. See this link to learn how to do this (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: [plot](https://www.dropbox.com/home/Data/Analysis%20Data%20~%20Amos?preview=Disaster+Distribution.pdf)

Comment: I need to group the regions,expand coverage to see whole map,zooming some areas and some colours are not clearly distinguishables

Comment: I cannot see the plot. In addition, I think it would be great if you post a new question.